# How can I create babbage era tx. Whats the difference from Alonzo Era?

Tags: vasil-hard-fork

I can't use my old Tx creator (cardano-cli) from Alonzo era.

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error:
 The era of the node and the tx do not match.
  The node is running in the Babbage era, but the transaction is for the Alonzo era.
  \n"}
```

How can I create babbage era tx. Whats the difference from Alonzo Era?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably just add **--babbage-era** to your **cardano-cli transaction build** *(or build-raw)* command. You'll see this option when you enter **cardano-cli transaction build -h**.

As per [this issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3900) and [this comment](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3900#issuecomment-1150514216) the alonzo-era is still set as the default for now.

Regarding the differences, the babbage era brings lots of new features and possibilities, that you can find a good technical [overview of here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases/tag/1.35.0), including: reference inputs, reference scripts, inline datums and much more.